# AWS CLI eb create error LargeZipFile

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Getting the following error when trying to create an environment in AWS using eb create:

```
$ eb create django-env
```

> Creating application version archive "app-XXXXXX_XXXXXX".
>       ERROR: LargeZipFile :: Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions

Comment: How big is the Django application? I did a test and like the `zipfile` docs say, you shouldn't need zip64 unless the directory is larger than 4GB. Be sure that `eb` isn't trying to zip up a really large directory like `~/` or something.

Comment: i have the same problem , but I didn't mentioned any specific location to the eb. where is he looking?

Comment: eb is using the current directory which you are in if not configured otherwise -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add
How big is your project folder?

Comment: use cd to go inside your project folder(the place with manage.py) then run eb

Answer (score 0):

When you use `eb` commands, it first tries to create the zip file using the contents of your git repository (if I remember correctly with `git  ls-files`), then if it doesn't find one, send the contents of the folder. Try:

- creating a new folder
- copy your code
- `git init`
- `git commit`

and then

- `eb create django-dev`